# Display result as group by count with max date?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below sample data, that I need to display results as count by group with max date.

```
REQUEST_NUMBER  ASSIGNED_GROUP  LAST_MODIFIED_DATE
001             GROUP A         
001             GROUP B         2/2/2018
002             GROUP A         
002             GROUP B         2/2/2018
002             GROUP C         2/3/2018
003             GROUP B
```

My expected result needs to be displayed as count of a group with max of last_modified_date only like:

```
ASSIGNED_GROUP  TOTAL_COUNT
GROUP B         2
GROUP C         1
```

In my above example 001 was last assigned to GROUP B, 002 last assigned to GROUP C, and 003 is only 1 record with NULL last_modified_date, so remains with GROUP B.

I'm trying with just one result so far, but not getting proper results:

```
SELECT request_number, ASSIGNED_GROUP_NAME
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY request_number ORDER BY request_number) RNUM,
           request_number, ASSIGNED_GROUP_NAME
    FROM WORK_DETAIL
    WHERE request_number = '3458112'
    )
WHERE MAX(last_modified_date)
ORDER BY ASSIGNED_GROUP_NAME
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could work

```
    SELECT ASSIGNED_GROUP, COUNT(ASSIGNED_GROUP), MAX(LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY ASSIGNED_GROUP
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `group by`;

```
select t.assigned_group,t.last_modified_date,count(*) from table t inner join
(
    select assigned_group,max(last_modified_date) as maxDate from table 
    where last_modified_date is not null
    group by assigned_group
) t2 
ON t.last_modified_date = t2.maxDate and t.assigned_group = t2.assigned_group
group by t.assigned_group,t.last_modified_date
```

Comment: This isn't considering record by max(last_modified_date)

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajoin with a subquery with max_date group by assigned_group

```
select a.ASSIGNED_GROUP, count(*)
from my_table  a
inner join(

  select ASSIGNED_GROUP,  max(LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) as max_date
  from my_table 
  where LAST_MODIFIED_DATE is not null
  group by ASSIGNED_GROUP

) t on t.max_date = a.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE and t.ASSIGNED_GROUP = a.ASSIGNED_GROUP
group by a.assigned_group
```